# Qt widget resizes to width=256, while it shouldn't

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-designer, qtablewidget, qtreewidget

**Form setup:**

`QSplitter` (highlighted on the image) that contains `QTreeWidget` (left) and `QTableWidget` (right):

[image]

Non-default properties of these two widgets within QSplitter:

- `QTreeWidget`

  minimumSize / Width = 150
- `QTableWidget`

  minimumSize / Width = 300
  sizePolicy / Horizontal Stretch = 1

Basically the above setup specifies the minimum width of these two components, and that `QTableWidget`  is the one that will change it's width during form resize.
The buttons on the right side are placed in `QVBoxLayout` and it's size is fixed.

**Question:**

While resizing the form `QTreeWidget`'s width goes from minimum 150 up to unknown 256, and only then `QTableWidget` starts to grow, while I expect `QTreeWidget` to not grow in width at all, since `QTableWidget` is the one, that has Horizontal Stretch set to 1.

Please note, this has nothing to do with `QSplitter`, since the same happens when I place these two widgets in `QHBoxLayout` instead.

---

**UPDATE:**

Setting `QTreeWidget` maximumSize / Width to 150 (same as minimumSize / Width) to avoid resizing of this widget gives following:

[image]

`QTreeWidget` is fixed now to 150, but when the window is resized there is an empty gap between the two widgets. This gap grows up to 256-150=106, and then `QTableWidget` starts to expand.
Basically the result is similar, but this time area that was taken by `QTreeWidget` now is dedicated to this empty gap.

I've started to feel this might be a Qt bug.

**Technical info:**

- Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx) x86_64
- GCC 4.4.3
- Qt 4.6.2

Comment: And what is `QSizePolicy::Policy` for those widgets? What happens, if you set `QSizePolicy::Expanding` for `QTableWidget`?

Comment: `QSizePolicy` is default for both widgets, which is Expanding. Even if I set `QTreeWidget`'s Horizontal Policy to Minimum, the result is the same.

Comment: Try `QSizePolicy::Maximum` for `QTreeWidget`. And `QSizePolicy::Expanding` for `QTableWidget`  Minimum is not actually 'widget should have minimum size', read this doc: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qsizepolicy.html

Comment: Nope, setting `QTreeWidget`'s horizontal size policy to `Maximum` gives the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size hint of 256 width is hard-coded into `QAbstractScrollArea`. (Why? I have no idea.) Here is the method, from qabstractscrollarea.cpp:

```
QSize QAbstractScrollArea::sizeHint() const
{
    return QSize(256, 192);
#if 0
    Q_D(const QAbstractScrollArea);
    int h = qMax(10, fontMetrics().height());
    int f = 2 * d->frameWidth;
    return QSize((6 * h) + f, (4 * h) + f);
#endif
}
```

I'm not sure what's going on with the `0` macro ... maybe someone started to implement a non-hardcoded width but didn't finish, and this is for testing?

Anyhow, you can work around it by subclassing `QTreeView` and implementing your own size hint, for example:

```
class MyTreeView : public QTreeView {
public:
  explicit MyTreeView(QWidget *parent = NULL) : QTreeView(parent) { }
  QSize sizeHint() const {
    return QSize(150, 192);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `sizePolicy / HorizontalPolicy` to `Fixed` ?

Comment: Yes, changing sizePolicy to different values didn't solved this issue. But Dave Mateer provided the root cause of the problem.